# Кнопка перехода в окно Viber

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

Мне нужно сделать кнопку перехода в приложение Viber. Кнопка есть, и переход работает вот так:

```
Intent viber = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("viber://add?number=79101234567"));
```

Но мне нужно сделать, чтоб если viber не установлен кнопка перекидывала меня в маркет для установки этого приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так. 
[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/5797206)

```
   public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final String appPackageName = "com.viber.voip";
        boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot(appPackageName); 

        Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXName);

        buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(installed) {

            Intent viber = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("viber://add?number=79101234567"));
            startActivity(viber );

        } else {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
            } 
        }
        }); 



    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Я не опытный разработчик в android. Как это прикрутить к кнопке?

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте

Answer (score 1):

Проверка установлено приложение или нет:

```
private boolean isInstallApp(String appName) {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(appName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return packageManager.getApplicationInfo(appName, 0).enabled;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```